# Call parent function from an itemRenderer

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to call the parent function called "edit_groups()" from the itemRenderer. 
The code for my itemRenderer is:

```
<mx:VBox id="vbx_container" paddingBottom="4" paddingLeft="4" paddingRight="4" paddingTop="4" borderStyle="solid"
    dropShadowEnabled="true" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off" >
    <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off" >
        <mx:Image id="image" width="100" height="100" source="{data.thumb}" scaleContent="true" maintainAspectRatio="true"
            complete="{image_smoothing_handler(event);}" trustContent="true" doubleClick="{CALL THE PARENT FUNCTION "edit_groups()"}"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:VBox>
```

And I call my itemRenderer from an application like:

```
list_groups_modify.itemRenderer=new ClassFactory(groups.list_groups_modify_item_renderer);

<mx:Label text="{data.label}" textAlign="center" maxWidth="60" toolTip="{data.label}"/>
```

Regards
Zeeshan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, using `parentDocument`:

```
<mx:VBox id="vbx_container" paddingBottom="4" paddingLeft="4" paddingRight="4" paddingTop="4" borderStyle="solid"
    dropShadowEnabled="true" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off" >
    <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off" >
        <mx:Image id="image" width="100" height="100" source="{data.thumb}" scaleContent="true" maintainAspectRatio="true"
            complete="{image_smoothing_handler(event);}" trustContent="true" doubleClick="parentDocument.edit_groups()"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:VBox>
```

Comment: @Zeeshan - Sorry wasn't thinking right, try `parentDocument` instead, answer updated.

Comment: I thought this would answer my identical problem, but I am getting error 1069 instead. Whilst the compiler lets me through, at run time I am told it cannot find my public function!

Comment: (My itemrenderer is in a seperate MXML file in Flash Builder 4)

Comment: I also get the exception #1069 upon trying to call the method on the parentDocument.   When the renderer is part of an s:List, the parentDocument is pointing at spark.skins.spark.ListSkin.

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the `outerDocument` like this

```
<mx:VBox id="vbx_container" paddingBottom="4" paddingLeft="4" paddingRight="4" paddingTop="4" borderStyle="solid"
    dropShadowEnabled="true" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off" >
    <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off" >
        <mx:Image id="image" width="100" height="100" source="{data.thumb}" scaleContent="true" maintainAspectRatio="true"
            complete="{image_smoothing_handler(event);}" trustContent="true" doubleClick="{outerDocument.edit_groups()}"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure what you are trying to reference is set to a public function or variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting error **1069** and your item renderer is a separate **mxml component** you may need to 
use:

```
parentDocument.parentDocument.functionName();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced similar situations, but according to me the best way is to dispatch some custom event from the item renderer and catch that event inside the parent component. Inside the eventlistener call the parent's function. This will work even if the itemrenderer is in separate mxml file or actionscript class.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this post having a similar problem following an upgrade to Flex SDK 4.6. I was getting the dreaded error 1069 with code that used to work fine. The preferred answer did not work.

However, I solved it by changing it to use:

```
document.owner.parentDocument
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this piece of code (placed in the item renderer) to find the next applicable parent:

```
internal function findTarget():MyTargetClass
{
    for (var p:* = this; !(p is MyTargetClass || p == null); p = p.parentDocument) {}
    return p;
}
```

Usage example:

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    super.data = value;
    findTarget().myFunction(value);
}
```